# How to make Python do something every half an hour?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like my code (Python) to execute every half an hour. I'm using Windows. For example, I would like it to run at 11, 11:30, 12, 12:30, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Uh, assuming that "nothing breaks" if two copies of your script happen to run at the same time (or if your script's runtime is much shorter than 30 minutes), you either want [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) or [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: To overcome possible problems of script running longer than your intended interval, use the Linux `at`, `atq` and `atrm` commands. Schedule a job to run using `at` and at the end of the script reschedule it with `at` again.

Comment: @marekful I don't have Linux. I have Windows. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should call the function once, then wait 1800 second(half an hour), call function, wait, ect.

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


def func():
    your actual code code here


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Thread(target = func).start()
    while True:
        sleep(1800)
        Thread(target = func).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

You can also use the [AT](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) command in the command prompt, which is similar to cron in linux.