# How do i do something each hour like increment a variable in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to trigger an event in python but for simplicity, lets say I want to increment a variable each hour. How can i do so?

Till now I am only able to generate the actual time in string format using this piece of code.

```
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

How can I only take hour from this time so that when that changes i will increment the variable or Please suggest any other way to increment a variable each hour.

Comment: `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now().hour`

Comment: If you don't care about the exact time of the day but only that the time interval should be one hour, you can use `time.sleep(3600)` to wait one hour (3600 seconds). You can then put this in a while loop together with the variable update.

Comment: @jmd_dk this is by far the least reliable way one can achieve that. One should relay on the `os` (ie cron if using Linux or the scheduled tasks mechanism if using Windows) than on the Python interpreter with `sleep`.

Comment: @DeepSpace that depends on the problem. The question is about doing something *in Python*. Explicitly calling out to the operating system for this simple task is not necessary. For many purposes, cron is the way to go, but then leave Python out of it all together. Also, exactly how is `time.sleep` *unreliable*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)
last_update = datetime.now()

# do long-running stuff

now = datetime.now()
if now - last_update > HOUR:
    # update()
    last_update = now
```

this does not do something each hour, but triggers `update` (whatever that is) if the last `update` was more than one hour ago.

[here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273965/4954037) that runs a thread in the background and executes every (half) hour